# Do php unused imports affect performance?

Tags: php, namespaces

If this question is a duplicate, please redirect me as I could not find the same question asked for PHP specifically.

I know the impact of import statements with Java and Python, but since PHP works differently, does it matter if I leave unused import (use) statements like such?

```
use DateTime;
```

Reason I'm asking instead of just removing is because I'm about to launch a refactored website and unless this has a large performance effect, I would rather leave them there instead of risking something breaking live.

Comment: Not at all. A `use` statement doesn't actually result in any extra code being imported, it's purely an alias for other code contained in the same file.

Comment: Thanks iainn! You can write an answer if you wish

Comment: As an aside, if you're interested in programmatically removing unused namespace declarations, have a look at [PHP Coding Standards Fixer](https://cs.sensiolabs.org/) aka php-cs-fixer

Answer (score 4):

`use` statements merely create aliases that can later be used instead of a full namespace reference, and is not actually required to refer to a class from another namespace - any class, interface etc can be referred to using the entire path without a `use`. as long as it has already been declared by e.g. autoload.

This can be easily demonstrated by having an entirely invalid `use`:

```php
use NotA\Valid\ClassName;
```

This doesn't throw any error until you actually attempt to use the reference `ClassName`. On the contrary:

```php
$obj = new \Some\Valid\Class($param);
```

This works just fine even though there is no matching `use` (as long as the class exists at the supplied path).

A long string of `use` statements at the start of a file can be distracting, while being able to use aliases may enhance readability of the rest of the source or exist simply for the developer's convenience. If there is a performance impact it is so marginal as to be nonexistent.